# Removing snapshot after removing guest hard disc

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, snapshot, virtual-disk

I have a server with ESXi 5.5 installed. I recently wanted to add a new hard disk to one of the guests. After adding the virtual disk to it, I took a snapshot just to be sure that nothing would go wrong (which unfortunately did).

After taking the snapshot, I proceeded to setup the new hard disk in my guest OS. Some minutes later I noticed that the guest is no longer working due to the storage being full, so I removed a file in the datastore which I thought wouldn't be necessary, but turned out to be important for the virtual disk recently added (probably had something to do with the snapshot). Then I removed the new hard disk from the guest OS in the `Hardware` tab of `Virtual Machine Properties`, and was able to start the guest once again.

The problem is that now, the snapshot is growing, and I surely don't want that. Is it safe to remove it now that the guest is working? In the panicking moments of my guest OS being down, I once tried to `go to` that snapshot, but obviously failed due to the file I removed. Is removing that file is gonna be a problem also for deleting the snapshot? And what can I do to be sure nothing would go wrong?

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. Comment me and I will edit it with the necessary information.

Comment: Oh my... Is this a production system?

Comment: @ewwhite Emmm... Unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your snapshot will grow in size as the state of the VM ages.

To safely remove the snapshot:

- Ensure your VM is in a safe state (If you're uncertain here, shut it down)
- If possible, make sure the datastore running the VM has a recent backup
- Open the Snapshot in the Vmware console and delete it
- If you shutdown your system, power it on and check out the results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but removing the snapshot is the easy part. My question is "Is there gonna be a problem with the missing disk?".
Also, how can I safely take a backup?